# How do you create a UTType for System Declared Uniform Type Identifiers for folder?

Tags: swift, icons, uti, nsworkspace

I see all kinds of examples for using a file or an extension but I am trying to call `let imag = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(for: <#T##UTType#>)` and I don't see any init method in UUType that takes a identifier e.g. `folder`.

Comment: `let imag = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(for: UUType.folder) ` is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UTType` is declared in the Uniform Type Identifiers framework.

All uou need to do is `import UniformTypeIdentifiers` and then you'll be able to write things like `UTType.folder`.